# Sails js load partial view from assets folder not from views

Tags: sails.js, partials

Given the following code:

```
<html>
<body>
<%- partial('myPartial.html') %>
</body>
</html>
```

It will work if I place **myPartial.html** in the views folder, however what I'm trying to do is to pull the view from the .tmp/public folder.

I've tried importing a script from the same location and it work so I think it might be related to `partial()`.

Does anyone has solved this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.tmp/public` is generated from the `assets` folder, processed by  default grunt tasks. It is used by Sails when serving [assets](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/assets) at runtime. So when serving assets, like scripts and styles, the path is relative to *.tmp/public*.

On the other hand, [partials](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/views/partials) are used when rendering ejs, and the relative path depends on the view that you working on. Partials really belong to the `views` folder. But if you ***really*** need to use an html from the assets in a partial, then you have to access myPartial.html relative to the current view.

Let us say you myPartial.html is in `.tmp/public/myPartial.html`, then your view should be something like

**views/homepage.ejs**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <%- partial('../.tmp/public/test.html') %>
  </body>
</html>
```